# Image Helper doesn't render the image (MVC3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

I'm trying to create an image helper that will render the image but my helper does not render the image. All I can see is shown in the screenshot below. Can anyone help spot the reason why? Please help. Here's my code.

**Helper Class**

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace CMS.Helpers
{
    public static class ImageHelper
    {

        public static string Image(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string fileName, string id, string alt, string contentPath)
        {
            var imgDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["imageDirectory"];
            var imagePath = string.Format("{0}{1}", imgDirectory, contentPath);
            var file = string.Format("{0}{1}", imagePath, fileName);
            var img = new TagBuilder("img");
            img.MergeAttribute("src", file);
            img.MergeAttribute("alt", alt);
            return img.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@Html.Image("TestImage.jpg", "testImg", "TestImg", "/Content/Uploads/MySiteImages")
```

**Web.Config**

```
<add key="imageDirectory" value="http://localhost:49191"/>
```

**Screenshot**
[image]

When entering the image url `"http://localhost:49191/Content/Uploads/MySiteImages/TestImage.jpg"` on the browser I see that the image exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that Razor automatically HTML encodes every `string` which is written to the response with the `@` symbol.

You can turn off the automatic encoding with `Html.Raw` method:

```
@Html.Raw(Html.Image("TestImage.jpg", "testImg", "TestImg", 
                     "/Content/Uploads/MySiteImages"))
```

Or you can return `MvcHtmlString` from your helper. This is the more idiomatic way in ASP.NET MVC and in this case razor won't encode your HTML so you don't need to remember to use `Html.Raw`:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
     string fileName, string id, string alt, string contentPath)
{
     var imgDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["imageDirectory"];
     var imagePath = string.Format("{0}{1}", imgDirectory, contentPath);
     var file = string.Format("{0}{1}", imagePath, fileName);
     var img = new TagBuilder("img");
     img.MergeAttribute("src", file);
     img.MergeAttribute("alt", alt);
     return MvcHtmlString.Create(img.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
}
```